# 700,000 rows w/ 40 parameters divided into 1,000 row blocks and formatted so each block occurs on the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, phpexcel, vba

The 700,000 rows containing the 40 delimited parameters are adjacent to another row that splits the rows up into blocks based on the minute of the day.  For the sake of simplicity let's say the 700,000 rows are split into blocks of 1,000 i.e., the first 1,000 rows occur at 1 minute, the second 1,000 rows occur at 2 minutes and so on.  This produces 700 blocks of rows and each block contains 1,000 rows.  I need help merging all the rows for each minute onto one row, so that all the data that occurs on the first minute of my dataset is on the same row.  The same goes for all the data that occurs on the 2nd minute, the 3rd minute, the 4th minute... all the way up to the 700th minute, so in the end I will have 700 rows of data and each row will represent the minute the dataset was taken. on.

**What I've Tried:**
IF(logical_test,value_if_true) Insert OFFSET into value_if_true yields 
IF(logical_test,OFFSET(**reference**,rows,columns,[height],[width]))
IF(B1:B1000=1,OFFSET(C1,0,-1,1,1) 
the height and the width in my equation are set to one, because I cannot get the formula to return multiple columns or rows.  I've tried inserting C1:C1000 for the height and C:C for the width, but it gives me a #ref error

I've also tried dragging the formula down 1,000 rows, which works, however, I'd rather not enter the formula 700,000 times, because it does not place the data all in one row **and** I'd have to place 40 empty rows in between each entry so that when I delimit the data it does not overlap.  I'm aware the 40 columns in between shouldn't be expected, because it wasn't part of my formula, but I mention it only because I also need help with this aspect.

**Edit:**

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx39C.jpg)

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbFLP.jpg)

Comment: Your question is very hard to follow, please try to edit the question so that it explains more clearly what you mean.

Comment: Is it always the same number of rows per block (e.g. 1000)? The short answer might be that you need to feed four numbers into your OFFSET not ranges, so rows(C1:C1000) and columns(C:C) rather than just C1:C1000 and C:C.

Comment: I tried several variations of what you suggested and it returned #VALUE.  Thanks though

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? You will likely need some sort of array concatenation, so unless you have Excel 2016 you will need a VBA solution.

Comment: @nbayly you're correct, I utilized =IF(B1=1,INDEX(C1,1,0)) and then expanded the equation down the spreadsheet.  Thanks

Comment: So have you found an answer yourself? If so I'd quite like to see it.

Comment: @TomSharpe =IF(B1=1,CONCAT(C1:C1000,)) then I tried prefixing a list of numbers from 1 to 28 million with a $ sign so I could find and replace all the relevant numbers with the CONCAT formula e.g., find $2,000 and replace with =IF(B1=2,CONCAT(C1:C1000,)). The dollar sign was a unique identifier.  I was going to then look at the macro it recorded and alter the VBA generated so I didn't have to perform the find and replace process 700 times over.  Never got that far though as Excel limits column size to ~16,000 and row size to ~1.5 million when I need 28 million.  So I Just downloaded R

Comment: I still don't get why you need so many rows, but I do see that you would run up against the 32K string length limit if you were trying to concat the 1,000 rows into one cell. Anyway fine if R will solve it.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe you were correct all along - I don't need that many rows.  I was primarily trying to format the data for machine learning, however, having too many parameters in one row convoluted the data anyways.